# How to make my JSON nicer in java ? Strictly using - org.json.JSON

Tags: java, json, string, list

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class testjson {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("name", "timmy");
        json.put("age", "20");

        List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>(); 
        JSONObject jsonIds = new JSONObject();

        jsonIds.put("jobId", "123");
        jsonIds.put("houseId", "5");


        ids.add(jsonIds.toString(4));

        json.put("idList", ids);

        System.out.println(json.toString(4));

    }

}
```

I want to print this out. The order of it doesn't matter but to fix the array as well.

```
{
    "age": "20",
    "name": "timmy",
    "idList": [
        {
            "houseId": "5", 
            "jobId": "123"
        }
    ]

}
```

Currently this outputs

```
{
    "age": "20",
    "idList": ["{\n    \"houseId\": \"5\",\n    \"jobId\": \"123\"\n}"],
    "name": "timmy"
}
```

as you can see the idList isn't what I want. I tried playing around with it but nothing was working. Does anyone know if this is possible with this standard json library? Or any other library that eclipse has that I wont have to separately download like jackson or gson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `toString` when you create `JSON Object`. Do it once, at the end when whole `JSON` is created.

In your code should be:

```
ids.add(jsonIds);
```

Below code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class OrgJsonApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
      root.put("name", "timmy");
      root.put("age", "20");


      JSONObject ids = new JSONObject();
      ids.put("jobId", "123");
      ids.put("houseId", "5");

      JSONArray idList = new JSONArray();
      idList.put(ids);

      root.put("idList", idList);

      System.out.println(root.toString(4));
  }
}
```

prints:

```
{
    "name": "timmy",
    "idList": [{
        "jobId": "123",
        "houseId": "5"
    }],
    "age": "20"
}
```

To change format for array is not easy and requires to extend base class. The simplest way is to create `org.json` package:

```
package org.json;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class JSONArrayIndent extends JSONArray {

    @Override
    public Writer write(Writer writer, int indentFactor, int indent) throws JSONException {
        try {
            boolean commanate = false;
            int length = this.length();
            writer.write('[');

            if (length > 0) {
                final int newindent = indent + indentFactor;

                Iterator<Object> iterator = iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Object next = iterator.next();
                    if (commanate) {
                        writer.write(',');
                    }
                    if (indentFactor > 0) {
                        writer.write('\n');
                    }
                    JSONObject.indent(writer, newindent);
                    try {
                        JSONObject.writeValue(writer, next,
                            indentFactor, newindent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new JSONException("Unable to write JSONArray value: " + next, e);
                    }
                    commanate = true;
                }
                if (indentFactor > 0) {
                    writer.write('\n');
                }
                JSONObject.indent(writer, indent);
            }
            writer.write(']');
            return writer;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new JSONException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And in above example change one line:

```
JSONArray idList = new JSONArrayIndent();
```

After that it prints:

```
{
    "name": "timmy",
    "idList": [
        {
            "jobId": "123",
            "houseId": "5"
        }
    ],
    "age": "20"
}
```

But I am not sure it is worth because `JSON` indention does not change anything in client-server communication. Moreover, we should keep our `JSON` payload as small as we can and format it only on demand.

Comment: Not quite what I want tho. Looks better than mine but the array brackets arent 4 lines https://gyazo.com/63e22629478e2f4bca5a7f5fd5bff82f

Comment: @bob It does not only look better than yours, it is the correct JSON you want (whereas yours is not, it has broken the nested object). Is the formatting that important?

Comment: @bob, how array is printed out to `JSON` is defined in `JSONArray.write` method. If you have one element in array it is shown as in example, when you have two or more object it is intended like you want.

Comment: Oh I see, it works as intended. Anyway to fix this 1 array issue? Unless that is also the correct json format for a 1 element json

Answer (score 1):

The `org.json` classes only allow you to set starting indentation level, and the number of spaces per level.  That's it.

As you have discovered, you cannot finesse the problem by formatting nested arrays and stitching them together.  The `org.json` APIs do not support this.

---

I tried looking for alternatives that offer better (more flexible) pretty printing.  If anything, GSON is even less flexible.  By contrast, the Jackson library offers a `PrettyPrinter` interface and base classes that you can use to implement your own custom pretty printers.  You can then use your custom class to instantiate an `ObjectWriter`.